# Error installing FFTW on macOS

Tags: macos, fftw

I am trying to install FFTW on my Mac, and am getting errors:

So I ran line by line in my terminal:

```
./configure --enable-shared
make
make install
```

Everything works, but when I run 'make install', I get the following error:

```
Making install in support
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in kernel
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in simd-support
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in dft
Making install in scalar
Making install in codelets
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in simd
Making install in common
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in sse2
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx-128-fma
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx2
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx2-128
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx512
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in kcvi
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in altivec
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in vsx
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in neon
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in generic-simd128
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in generic-simd256
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in rdft
Making install in scalar
Making install in r2cf
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in r2cb
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in r2r
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in simd
Making install in common
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in sse2
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx-128-fma
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx2
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx2-128
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in avx512
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in kcvi
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in altivec
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in vsx
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in neon
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in generic-simd128
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in generic-simd256
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[5]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in reodft
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in api
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  install-am
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/include'
mkdir: /usr/local/include: Permission denied
make[3]: *** [install-includeHEADERS] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Change `make install` to `sudo make install`. Or save yourself some grief and just use the ready-built stuff from [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Hey, thank you ever so much! :)... sudo installed working (and ill check out the homebrew link)